# Adding margin to move the text in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, padding

I want to insert the margin to the text so that i can move the text up little bi but the .PadTop is cannot be used. How to solve this problem?

```
    txtTitle.Text = StrConv(view, VbStrConv.Uppercase)
    txtTitle.Font.Size = 20
    txtTitle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Pink
    txtTitle.Font.Bold = True
    txtTitle.Pad.Top = 20
```

Comment: Are you talking Margin or padding here?  Because they are different things.  Way, I think of it Padding is space around the control, Magin is space between the edge of the control and the content.  Padding also has little effect without using layout tools such as docking

Comment: How to use margin invb. net?

Comment: *"How to use margin"*. How about you look for yourself first, then ask if you can't work it out? Assuming that this is a WinForms TextBox, the `Padding` and `Margin` properties are botht the same type - `Padding` - so they are used exactly the same way. BTW, the code you posted wouldn't compile. There is no `Pad` property and you can't set the `Size` or `Bold` properties of the `Font`.

Comment: i dont know how to add margin or padding, i dont know the keyword.

Comment: @Hursey The other way around -- Assuming WinForms, even though the properties you're showing there don't belong to this Platform: use a RichTextBox instead, it supports paragraph formatting (note that I didn't say it's as straightforward as setting a property)