# How to insert padding or margin in vb .net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to move up the word in vb.net. I dont know how to use padding or margin in vb.net. I want to add margin in below code.

```
txtTitle.Text = StrConv(view, VbStrConv.Uppercase)
txtTitle.Font.Size = 20
txtTitle.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Pink
txtTitle.Font.Bold = True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding margin to move the text in VB .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74819476/adding-margin-to-move-the-text-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like this?

```
myPanel.MarginTop = New Unit(15, UnitType.Pixel)
myPanel.MarginBottom = New Unit(15, UnitType.Pixel)
myPanel.MarginLeft = New Unit(20, UnitType.Pixel)
myPanel.MarginRight = New Unit(20, UnitType.Pixel)
```

Comment: Its come to error which is " 'Padding' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'."

Comment: @RajaAzrolAlimi - based on your feedback, I made a change to the answer. If that doesn't work can you provide more info on the version on vb?

Comment: Im using the latest version